# How to stop swiper.js from scrolling slides out of view

Tags: angular, swiper.js

Environment is angular+ionic, swiperjs works well except I can't figure out how to stop it from swiping the last images out of view, leaving the whole box empty?

I only have two images in the array `images`, so technically they shouldn't scroll out of view (I think?). Swiper template code:

```
<div *ngIf="images.length"
            style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center"
          >
            <div style="cursor: pointer" *ngIf="images.length > 1">
              <ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline" size="large" (click)="swipeprev()">
              </ion-icon>
            </div>

            <!-- class="full" -->
            <swiper
              #swiper
              pager="true"
              [spaceBetween]="30"
              [pagination]="{
                clickable: true
              }"
              [rewind]="true"
                [centerInsufficientSlides]="true"
                [watchOverflow]="true"

              class="toolswipercontainer"
            >
              <ng-template
                swiperSlide
                *ngFor="let image of images"
                class="toolinfoslide"
              >
                <div class="squarefit">
                  <img
                    [src]="image.cached"
                    (click)="imagemodal(images, image.url)"
                  />
                </div>
              </ng-template>
            </swiper>

            <div style="cursor: pointer" *ngIf="images.length > 1">
              <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" size="large" (click)="swipenext()">
              </ion-icon>
            </div>
          </div>
```

[image: Initial load]

[image: After swiping left]

Comment: can you please make a stackblitz example of your code.

Comment: I have the same issue - do you have a solution to your problem?

Comment: I'll google how to create a stackblitz o_O. Meanhwile I added an answer with a working solution ("working" as in "working the way I want" :D )

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling a little, this is my working template. Behavior is now, as I want:

- The first image is centered
- I can drag the images left/right or use the command divs to switch images
- The images no longer scroll out of view - on clicking Next on the last image, it just resets and scrolls back to image #1.

```html
          <div
            *ngIf="images.length"
            style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center"
          >
            <div
              style="cursor: pointer"
              *ngIf="images.length > 1"
              (click)="swipeprev()"
            >
              <ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline" size="large"> </ion-icon>
            </div>
            <swiper
              #swiper
              class="toolswipercontainer"
              [config]="slideOpts"
            >
              <ng-template
                swiperSlide
                *ngFor="let image of images"
                class="toolinfoslide"
              >
                <div class="squarefit">
                  <img
                    style="margin: auto"
                    [src]="image.cached"
                    (click)="imagemodal(images, image.url)"
                  />
                </div>
              </ng-template>
            </swiper>
            <div
              style="cursor: pointer"
              *ngIf="images.length > 1"
              (click)="swipenext()"
            >
              <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" size="large"> </ion-icon>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And ts code:

```
slideOpts = {
    spaceBetween: 25,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    watchOverflow: true,
    pagination: { clickable: true },
    rewind: true,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next-unique',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev-unique',
    },
  } as SwiperOptions;

images = [
 {
  url: '<image url>',
  cached: '<base64 data>';
 },
 …
];

@ViewChild('swiper', { static: false }) swiper?: SwiperComponent;

swipeprev() {
    this.swiper.swiperRef.slidePrev(100);
  }
  swipenext() {
    this.swiper.swiperRef.slideNext(100);
  }
```